# Under what condition is angular momentum conserved in both classical and quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, potential, commutator

Classically, angular momentum is only conserved in a central potential by considering the torque (correct me if I am wrong). In quantum mechanics, it is also true, isn't it?

If this is the case, then does it mean that in an infinite spherical well ($V(r)=0$ for $r<a$, and $V(r)= \text{inf}$ for $r>a$) the angular momentum is also conserved because $V$ depends on $r$ only? Also does it mean that in a 2D/3D square well it is not conserved because the potential is not radial?

Besides, usually we consider $L^2$ instead of $\vec L$. But if angular momentum is conserved and $[L^2,H]=0$, then does it automatically imply $[\vec L,H]=0$?

Comment: related: [How does commutation between the hamiltonian and angular momentum operator (squared) imply conservation of Angular momentum?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/234810/)

Comment: L is a vector, so say $[L_x,H]$, $[L_y,H]$, $[L_z,H]$.

Comment: *"Classically, angular momentum is only conserved in a central potential by considering the torque (correct me if I am wrong)."* In a collection of point particles or continuous bodies you need the strong form of Newton's 3rd law (so as you say, central potentials), but if you allow fields to carry momentum as well (as in classical E&M) then you no longer require the strong form, just that the momentum transfer occurs by local processes in the field. So you're only right about that in a limited subset of classical physics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Classically, angular momentum is only conserved in a central potential by considering the torque (correct me if I am wrong). In quantum mechanics, it is also true, isn't it?

In QM, an operator is conserved iff it commutes with $H$, because
$$
i\dot {\mathcal O}=[H,\mathcal O]
$$

Therefore, the angular momentum is conserved iff it commutes with $H$. As the kinetic term is rotationally invariant, you only need to consider the potential:
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} L^2=0\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad [V(R),L^2]=0
$$
that is, $L^2$ is conserved iff the potential is rotationally invariant, the same as in CM!

> Besides, usually we consider $L^2$ instead of $\vec L$. But if angular momentum is conserved and $[L^2,H]=0$, then does it automatically imply $[\vec L,H]=0$?

A scalar operator $A$ satisfies, by definition,
$$
R^\dagger A R=A
$$
where $R$ is any rotation. As $R= \exp[i \vec\theta\cdot\vec L]$, you can expand the relation above to first order in $\theta$ to check that it is equivalent to
$$
R^\dagger A R=A \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad [A,\vec L]=0
$$
so yes: a rotationally invariant operator commutes with the three components of the angular momentum operator.

Comment: What do $X^2$, $Y^2$, $Z^2$ mean? Functions that only depend on $x$, $y$ and $z$?

Comment: $L_x$, $L_y$, $L_z$ only depend on $\theta$ and $\phi$ if written in spherical coordinates. Using the above arguments, can I conclude that $[H,L_i]=0$ if $V(r)$ is central?

Comment: 1) $X=x$, $Y=y$, $Z=z$ (it's just that some books write capital letters for operators) 2) I edited the post, but basically yes.